# Completeness of coefficient functionnals

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, duality

My questions is about Schauder bases and more specifically about coefficient functionals.

Let $(x_n)$ be a Schauder basis of a Banach space $X$. Thus for all $x$ in $X$, $x = \sum f_n(x) x_n$. The $f_n$ are called coefficient functionals.
They are continuous. If $X$ is reflexive, they form a basis of $X^*$ (with Hahn–Banach theorem). 
My question is : if $X$ is not reflexive, but if we suppose $X^*$ separable, is $(f_n)$ a basis of $X^*$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

M. Zippin [showed](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02771607) that for a Banach space $X$ with a basis, if every basis of $X$ is boundedly complete or if every basis of $X$ is shrinking, then $X$ is reflexive.

The result of Zippin answers you question in the negative (or, rather, the answer is, *"not necessarily"*.) However to complete the picture let us recall the earlier result of R.C. James (alluded to in your question) asserting the following: *For a reflexive Banach space $X$ with a basis $(x_n)$, the basis $(x_n)$ is both shrinking and boundedly complete.*

Putting the results of Zippin and James together yields the following:

*Let $X$ be a Banach space with a basis. The following are equivalent:*

- *$X$ is reflexive;*
- *every basis of $X$ is shrinking; and*
- *every basis of $X$ is boundedly complete.*

Answer (score 8):

No, there are counterexamples. For instance, there exists a space $X$ with a basis, $X^*$ separable, and yet $X^*$ fails approximation property. See  Lindenstrauss-Tzafriri's book Theorem 1.e.7 for a discussion of this (it is an existence proof).

Comment: The dual space $J^*$ of James' space, with the basis formed by the coefficient functionals of the (usual) shrinking basis of $J$, is another example.

Comment: Yes, in fact, that is a better answer:) But you mean boundedly complete basis (i.e., `the summing basis') of $J$

Comment: And Zippin showed that for a Banach space $X$ with a basis, if every basis of $X$ is boundedly complete or if every basis of $X$ is shrinking, then $X$ is reflexive: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02771607

Comment: @ Philip Brooker Nice. This should be the answer to the question.

Comment: @BunyaminSari Thanks, Bunyamin, I've just cobbled together an answer :)